# Entity Framework: Sort on Field of Derived Type

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm pretty sure I can't do what I want to do in EF4.3, but before I abandon the attempt I thought I'd run it by some more experienced programmers.

I have a schema where two entity types, 'person' and 'org', each derive from a root entity I call 'named'. This structure allows me to associate an instance of 'named' with instances of another entity called 'address' via a many-to-many relationship, 'entity_address', without having to distinguish between whether the 'named' entity is an organization or a person.

When I query entity_address I'd like to be able to sort the results by different properties depending upon whether the entity_address instance is a 'person' or an 'org'. In the case of a person the "input" to the sorting algorithm might be the value of the property "last_name", while for an org it might be the property "org_name".

If I try the obvious:

```
IQueryable<named> sorted = entities.OrderBy(x => ( x is person ) ? ( (person) x ).last_name : ( (org) x ).org_name);
```

when I access "sorted" EF throws an exception about only being able to cast primitive types. I presume it can't apply the cast operator to the "x" instance.

I've tried a lot of less obvious approaches, with no success :).

Is there a way to do this in LINQ to Entities?

I know I can solve the problem by denormalizing the database and sticking a "sort_field" in the entity 'named', and then just sort on that (I'd have to include logic for keeping the sort_field value consistent with changes to values in instances of person and org, but that's certainly feasible).

Comment: FWIW, I also realize I can do what I want using a custom function I put into the conceptual model to retrieve the appropriate text field(s) after testing for the entity type of a given instance of named. I'm curious, though, if there's a way to do it without writing a custom function (i.e., "directly" in Linq to Entities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is projecting both entities to the same (anonymous) type:

```cs
entities.OfType<Person>()
    .Select(p => new { p.Prop1, p.Prop2, ..., SortProp = p.last_name })
.Union(
    entities.OfType<Organization>()
        .Select(o => new { o.Prop1, o.Prop2, ..., SortProp = o.org_name }))
.OrderBy(x => x.SortProp)
```

The projections should have exactly the same properties in the same order.

Of course, you can also do the sorting in memory the way you already did, i.e. on `entities.ToList()`. But that defeats the purpose of doing it with `IQueryable`: letting the database do the work.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I had to modify your idea a bit, Gert, because 'org' and 'person' don't share the same set of properties, but that was trivial. The solution won't work with the rest of the system I've built, but that's not the fault of the solution -- it's just that I didn't describe the totality of specs the solution has to fit. But in terms of the specific question I posed, this definitely hits the mark.

Answer (score 0):

does this work? I'm assuming that `entities` is a collection of `named`...

`entities.OrderBy(x => x as person == null ? x.org_name : x.last_name)`

Comment: Sorry, Josh, but that won't work because 'named' doesn't contain either org_name or last_name as properties. Those are properties of 'org' and 'person', respectively.